# 'Getting Started' fabric-composer on mac - error starting Fabric or error deploying to fabric

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm following the instructions on https://fabric-composer.github.io/start/quickstart.html. Below is the version of the pre-requisites.

```
macOS 10.12.3
$> docker --version
Docker version 1.12.5, build 7392c3b
$> docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.8.2, build e18a919
$> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387
$> node --version
v6.4.0
$> npm --version
4.0.3
$> git --version
git version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)
```

When I run `npm install` the script never gets past this point:

```
# Wait for the Hyperledger Fabric to start.
while ! nc localhost 7051 </dev/null; do sleep 1; done
```

If I go into the scripts folder and run `docker-compose up --build`  (without the `-d` option), it does a bunch of seemingly valid startup stuff and then this output repeating over & over.

```
vp0_1         | 15:42:09.904 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 08f Touch service indicates no dropped connections
vp0_1         | 15:42:09.904 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 090 Connected to: []
vp0_1         | 15:42:09.904 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 091 Discovery knows about: []
vp0_1         | 15:42:15.903 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 092 Touch service indicates no dropped connections
vp0_1         | 15:42:15.903 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 093 Connected to: []
vp0_1         | 15:42:15.903 [peer] ensureConnected -> DEBU 094 Discovery knows about: []
```

When I then run the `deployNetwork` script, I get this error

```
getting-started> composer network deploy --archiveFile digitalPropertyNetwork.bna  --enrollId WebAppAdmin --enrollSecret DJY27pEnl16d
Deploying business network from archive digitalPropertyNetwork.bna
Business network definition:
    Identifier: digitalproperty-network@0.0.1
    Description: Digital Property Network
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:189:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:158:8)
    at readCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:217:12)
```

I guess my qestions are:

1. How do I verify that fabric is running correctly?
2. If it is running correctly, why is the deploy command giving an error?

*Update...*
The output of the `docker ps` command is

```
$> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                      NAMES
167c9b93d386        hyperledger/fabric-peer         "sh -c 'sleep 5; peer"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7050-7053->7050-7053/tcp                           scripts_vp0_1
8aedcfa73607        hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc   "membersrvc"             About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                                     scripts_membersrvc_1
```

Comment: Could you give the output of the `docker ps` command, please. The constantly repeating output is expected - this (in theory) is the running Hyperlegder Fabric.  

The last error message is consistent with nothing listening on the ports.

Comment: @calanais - answer updated with `docker ps` ouput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Docker Toolbox. I switched to Docker For Mac, and then this started working.

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Answer (score 1):

Since i ran into this just thought i would clear it up. the default connection profile which is created with the compose network deploy (without giving a specific connection profile) attempts to connect to localhost, since docker toolbox uses a VM you should modify the connection profile to that IP.

this is also the reason it worked for you in docker for mac.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there, it looks as though your fabric peer and memberservices nodes have been created correctly and are still running, but the deploy of the business network stage has failed.

You could use `docker logs -f 167c9b93d386` to see if there are any indications from the peer about why the deploy failed.

If there's no indication in there then I would be tempted to try again using:
`scripts/teardown.sh`
`rm -rf $HOME/.composer-credentials`
`npm install`